# Linter Setup: no line-break on imports including curly braces

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, babeljs, eslint

Started working with vue.js recently and I can't figure out why my import statements always break to a new line on save:

```js
import {
    businessSignup
} from './businessSignup.module';
import {
    user,
    guest
} from './people.module';
```

I'd really prefer the following code style.

```js
import { businessSignup } from './businessSignup.module';
import { user, guest } from './people.module';
```

I'm aware that there is babel-eslint, eslint, as well as my vscode editor, all suspect to play a role in this, however I'm not very experienced with linter configuration yet.
Hope there is a quick solution to this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my own error. Turns out it wasn't related to any of the stated tools like babel, eslint nor vscode settings.

I must have installed a quite popular extension called **Beautify** way back. I've disabled it for my particular workspace and now the curly braces stay in line.